# Compare two lines having the same key and determine whether a value is different or not

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which looks like this:

```
+ -------------+------------+------+-----------+-----------+
| M_PACK_INTID | M_PACK_REF | M_NB | M_XPFWSPT | M_BPFOLIO |
+ -------------+------------+------+-----------+-----------+
| 1.781        | 100        | 101  | 12        | PFOLIO    |
| 1.781        | 100        | 102  | 12        | PFOLIO    |
| 1.781        | 100        | 103  | 12        | PFOLIO    |
| 1.781        | 100        | 104  | 12.3      | PFOLIO    |
| 1.781        | 200        | 201  | 15        | PFOLIO    |
| 1.781        | 200        | 202  | 15        | PFOLIO    |
| 1.781        | 200        | 203  | 15        | PFOLIO    |
| 1.781        | 200        | 204  | 15        | PFOLIO    |
+ -------------+------------+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Basically we have, for each `M_PACK_REF`, 4 different `M_NB`, to which is assigned a potentially different `M_XPFWSPT`.

**EXPECTED RESULT:** I would like to extract all the `M_PACK_REF` for which the **first** and the **fourth** `M_NB` have a different value of `M_XPFWSPT`.
In the above example, that would be the case for `M_PACK_REF = 100` (since its `M_NB = 101` has a `M_XPFWSPT = 12` while the `M_NB = 104` has a `M_XPFWSPT = 12.3`).

Here is a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7aa6/9) where you can play around.

According to the data in this fiddle, the expected result would be something like this:

```
M_PACK_REF
100
400
```

I've tried to extract from this table the first and the last line for each `M_PACK_REF` and count the occurrencies of `M_XPFWSPT` which are different:

```
select M_PACK_REF
 from 
 (
    select M_PACK_REF, M_NB, M_XPFWSPT
    from GATHER
    where M_NB = (select min(M_NB) from GATHER G where G.M_PACK_REF = GATHER.M_PACK_REF)
    or M_NB = (select max(M_NB) from GATHER G where G.M_PACK_REF = GATHER.M_PACK_REF)
 )
 group by M_PACK_REF, M_NB, M_XPFWSPT
 having count (distinct M_XPFWSPT) > 1;
```

... but it shows me an empty table.
Could anyone please help?

Comment: are you sure that grouping over  `M_PACK_REF, M_NB, M_XPFWSPT` is that what you want? there no dublicats in your example

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: @D-Shih I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @jarlh I've added a fiddle for that :)

Comment: I've replaced the image with text, as this is the preferred way to show sample data here.

Comment: Thank you @ThorstenKettner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all number your rows, so get the first and fourth per `M_PACK_REF`. Then compare.

```
with numbered as
(
  select
    m_pack_ref,
    m_nb,
    m_xpfwspt,
    row_number() over (partition by m_pack_ref order by m_nb) as rn
  from gather
)
select *
from (select * from numbered where rn = 1) first
join (select * from numbered where rn = 4) fourth
  on  fourth.m_pack_ref = first.m_pack_ref
  and fourth.m_xpfwspt <> first.m_xpfwspt;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thorsten! You made a typo under your join, I'm editing it :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand corrcly you can just use `exists`  and `having` to make it.

```
select M_PACK_REF, M_NB, M_XPFWSPT
from GATHER g1
WHERE exists (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM GATHER g2
  HAVING
      min(g2.M_NB) = g1.M_NB OR MAX(g2.M_NB) = g1.M_NB 
  and 
      COUNT(distinct M_XPFWSPT) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks D-Shih, the problem with this query is that it only selects the highest and the lowest M_PACK_REF, but not all the others that might exist in between :)

Answer (score 1):

could you try this?

```
WITH filtered as 
(
SELECT 
    M_PACK_REF,
    M_XPFWSPT,
    COUNT(*) as Cnt
FROM GATHER
    WHERE M_NB like '%01' or M_NB like '%04'
GROUP BY M_PACK_REF, M_XPFWSPT
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)

SELECT DISTINCT M_PACK_REF FROM filtered
```

The idea that if values for M_XPFWSPT are different we will have by one row for each pair M_PACK_REF,  M_XPFWSPT. If M_XPFWSPT the same - count(*) will return 2